# git pull get conflict

Tags: git, pull-request

I try to `git pull --rebase` from gitlab.

```
Auto-merging app/Filament/Pages/Dashboard.php
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/Filament/Pages/Dashboard.php
Auto-merging app/Filament/Pages/Utility/TestBarcode.php
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/Filament/Pages/Utility/TestBarcode.php
Auto-merging app/Filament/Resources/Inbound/PutawayResource.php
Auto-merging app/Filament/Resources/Inbound/PutawayResource/Pages/ListPutaway.php
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/Filament/Resources/Inbound/PutawayResource/Pages/ListPutaway.php
Auto-merging app/Filament/Resources/Inbound/ReceivingResource/Pages/CreateNewPallet.php
Auto-merging app/Filament/Resources/Inventory/InventoryDetailResource.php
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/Filament/Resources/Inventory/InventoryDetailResource.php
Auto-merging app/Filament/Resources/Inventory/InventoryDetailResource/Pages/ViewInventoryDetail.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in app/Filament/Resources/Inventory/InventoryDetailResource/Pages/ViewInventoryDetail.php
Auto-merging app/Filament/Resources/Outbound/SalesOrderResource.php
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/Filament/Resources/Outbound/SalesOrderResource.php
Auto-merging app/Filament/Resources/Outbound/SalesOrderResource/Pages/ListSalesOrders.php
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/Filament/Resources/Outbound/SalesOrderResource/Pages/ListSalesOrders.php
Auto-merging composer.lock
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

How to resolve this issue and why keep receive this error?Anyone can help me? I am appreciate that you take times for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have what is called a `merge conflict` which is when you try to `pull` changes from the `remote repo` into your `local repo` and there are `competing changes`. Which means that there changes made to the same line of a file, or when one person edits a file and another person deletes the same file. If you look at the files in question you'll find the conflict markers `<<<<<<<`, `=======`, `>>>>>>>`. [Here](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/addressing-merge-conflicts/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line) is a `Github` tutorial on how to fix a `merge conflicts`. The main take away from the tutorial is the following:

> Decide if you want to keep only your branch's changes, keep only the
> other branch's changes, or make a brand new change, which may
> incorporate changes from both branches. Delete the conflict markers
> <<<<<<<, =======, >>>>>>> and make the changes you want in the final
> merge. In this example, both changes are incorporated into the final
> merge

Comment: Thanks for your help, i already fixed the problem. :)